# Turn html encoded string into array

Tags: javascript, html

I have this api call that returns a string, contaning a chunk of images. How can i convert that string into an array?

The string that gets returned lookls like below. Starts with a

tag since its a wordpress post.

Its all the image tags src is want in an array.

```
<p><img src=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg\" alt=\"thumb\" width=\"720\" height=\"510\" class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-52\" srcset=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg 720w, http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12-300x213.jpg 300w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 61vw, (max-width: 1362px) 45vw, 600px\" \/><br \/>\n<img src=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg\" alt=\"thumb\" width=\"720\" height=\"510\" class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-52\" srcset=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg 720w, http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12-300x213.jpg 300w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 61vw, (max-width: 1362px) 45vw, 600px\" \/><br \/>\n<img src=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg\" alt=\"thumb\" width=\"720\" height=\"510\" class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-52\" srcset=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg 720w, http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12-300x213.jpg 300w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 61vw, (max-width: 1362px) 45vw, 600px\" \/><br \/>\n<img src=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg\" alt=\"thumb\" width=\"720\" height=\"510\" class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-52\" srcset=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg 720w, http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12-300x213.jpg 300w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 61vw, (max-width: 1362px) 45vw, 600px\" \/><br \/>\n<img src=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg\" alt=\"thumb\" width=\"720\" height=\"510\" class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-52\" srcset=\"http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12.jpg 720w, http:\/\/local.pp.com\/api\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/thumb-12-300x213.jpg 300w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 61vw, (max-width: 1362px) 45vw, 600px\" \/><\/p>\n"
```

Comment: You want an array that will contain the `src` value of each `<img>`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ajyeb7ph/ probably not what you wanted but it is what you asked for. should probably clarify the question.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the SRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = myHTMLString;
var images = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Create a div, put the html in it and then use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to get the images.

getElementsByTagName returns an HTMLCollection, which is just like an array and can be iterated through the same way with an for loop.

```
for(var i=images.length; i--;){
    var image = images[i];
    // do stuff with each image
}
```

Edit: you say you want the src's in the array. look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/kev7hr2y/

Comment: This will make most browsers initiate an actual HTTP request to fetch the images. If we're only interested in the array of `src`s, that is an undesired side effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the string into DOM elements, then find all `<img>` and `map()` their `src` attribute:

```
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    parsedElms = parser.parseFromString(yourHTMLString, 'text/html'),
    imgs = parsedElms.getElementsByTagName('img');

var result = Array.prototype.map.call(imgs, function(e) { return e.getAttribute('src'); });
```